# Bug squash request

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the [Users page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter) (either the *quarter* view or *year* view), when I hover over Barrie England's rep, the popup shows the amount twice (along with the total rep):

[image]

In the *week*, *month*, or *all* views, or for other users, the popup is calculated correctly:

[image]

Before you sigh in disbelief at my pettifogging, check out the [voters](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters) tab or the [editors](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors) tab, in any view except *all*.  Every single user has their total reputation no less than three identical times on the popup, even where it says it's the rep for the month or week or whatever:

[image]

Sigh all you want.

**Edit:** Hovering over Barrie's rep in the [quarter view of the rep user tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2gHI.png) still brings up a buggy popup:

[image: ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2gHI.png)]

**Further edit:**  And [now that's about to be fixed too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126462/164012).

Comment: I seldom sigh in disbelief anymore at pettifogging.

Comment: I'm a great believer in the idea that apparently trivial glitches may be of interest to devs, because they may be indicative of more serious problems "below the waterline". Anyway, in checking this one out (not that I disbelieved you - I just wanted to get a feel for it), I ended up clicking on the "editors" tab for the first time ever. And realised that my ranking there is noticeably lower than on *rep* or *votes*, so I guess I should shake a leg and make a bit more effort in that respect (thanks for nothing, @Daniel! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126280/164012) to *Hover popup shows wrong/duplicate rep for week/month/etc in user profile page*, the question I posted on MSO after I realized the bug was on every site:

> Thanks, this will be fixed in the next build.

For those of you who don't understand the terminology used in the quoted answer, it means *the bug will soon be squashed*.

Comment: Ah, right. So *status-completed* is just an optimistic way of looking at things? I think there's a flaw in the logic there. Suppose the devs *think* they've fixed it, but actually they fail? Perhaps we should have another tag called *status-really-completed* that the OP (or anyone else, come to that) could add once we've seen that it really *is* fixed.

Comment: @Fumble: perhaps the *status-completed* tag should read *we think we've fixed this one, but no guarantees*?

Comment: ... or more precisely, *"we think we **will have fixed this one soon**, but no guarantees"*? I suppose if the relevant dev doesn't assign the flag until *after* he's made a change and seen that it seems to be fixed, it's a reasonable approach. But not if the dev just sets the flag to mean *"Okay - I've seen the bug report. I'll remember and fix that tomorrow"*. Then goes off sick for a while, and it slips through the net.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There's a difference between *status-completed* (that is, re-coding is done) and *status-implemented* or whatever the equivalent is in SO (that is, the users can use the re-coded software).

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Sounds good in principle, but I note that if I search for [status-completed] here on meta, I get lots of hits. Sadly, [status-implemented] gets none at all!

Comment: In this case it ended up that [they didn't fully fix it the first time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126462/164012), and [had to try again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126490/164012).